# Spring postForObject returning 400 Bad Request

Tags: java, spring, resttemplate

So, i have that method in my Java application:

```
public String addAppointment(String service_id, String location_id, String start_date, String client_name, String client_phone, String client_email, String note, String session_token)
{
    Map<String, String> args = new HashMap<String, String>();

    args.put("service_id", service_id);
    args.put("location_id", location_id);
    args.put("start_date", start_date);
    args.put("client_name", client_name);
    args.put("client_phone", client_phone);
    args.put("client_email", client_email);
    args.put("note", note);

    System.out.println(API_URL + "company/[censored]/appointment/?session_token="+ session_token);

    String result = restTemplate.postForObject(API_URL + "company/[censored]/appointment/?session_token="+ session_token, args, String.class);

    return result;
}
```

And i got that warning:

```
WARNING: POST request for "http://www.setster.com/api/v2/company/[censored]/appointment/?session_token=[censored]" resulted in 400 (Bad Request); invoking error handler
WARNING: StandardWrapperValve[setster]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet setster threw exception
```

When i change that line:

```
String result = restTemplate.postForObject(API_URL + "company/[censored]/appointment/?session_token="+ session_token, args, String.class);
```

for:

```
String result = restTemplate.getForObject(API_URL + "company/[censored]/appointment/?session_token="+ session_token, String.class, args);
```

I receive a success message from server with the right response. But, the POST URL is fine and works in PHP with CURL with no problems.

So my question is. What i'm doing wrong? There is another options to create a post with **postForObject**?

Comment: Did you made http post request in PHP with CURL ?

Comment: Yes. By using a URL i created a POST request in CURL.